# SQL could not find server - though the query is searching the DBname as the server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL query in SSMS where I am trying to look for the phrase ATLAS within the SUNAME of selected databases.

When I run this, I get a `Could not find server 'DB1' in sys.servers.` where `DB1` is quoting the database name...so in affect it thinks the database name is the server I presume?

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Sql =
STUFF(
(SELECT
    NCHAR(10) + N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(10) +
N'SELECT
    '+ QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + N' AS dbName,
    SUNAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.PL.ACCOUNTS
            WHERE SUNAME = ''ATLAS'''
FROM sys.databases d
where name like '%AccountsLive'
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 11, '');
exec( @Sql );
```

Running a `print( @Sql)` of this comes up with the below, which looks fine to me?

```
SELECT
    'DB1' AS dbName,
    SUNAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        FROM [DB1].dbo.PL.ACCOUNTS
            WHERE SUNAME = 'ATLAS'
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many periods in the name.

The structure is `[server name].[database name].[schema name].[object name]`

In this structure you have :

Object Name = 'ACCOUNTS'
Schema Name = 'PL'
Database Name = 'dbo'
Server Name = 'DB1'

I thik you need to also add `[]` around `PL.ACCOUNTS`

Comment: Yup, so just change dbo.PL.ACCOUNTS to dbo.[PL.ACCOUNTS]

Comment: Using periods within table names is VERY POOR practice.   If you need a separator then use an underscore

Comment: Thanks for the responses for this (sorry for the delay in getting back - been stuck in meetings!).....I've tried `dbo.[PL.ACCOUNTS]` and now getting an invalid object name? I need to look further into this I think, unless anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Is your schema name actually ```PL``` ?   In which case drop the ```dbo```

Comment: Sorry, after going back to check the table name is `PL_ACCOUNTS` and not `PL.ACCOUNTS`.....sorry for wasting everyone's time!!